# Image not visible while using dynamic image source - MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create an image slideshow using MVC5. Here is my model class:

```
public class ImageSlider
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

For this model, I'd created a controller and an action within:

```
public ActionResult _imageSlider()
{
    return View(new List<ImageSlider> {
       new ImageSlider { Source = "~/_Slider/Images/google.jpg" },
       new ImageSlider { Source = "~/_Slider/Images/googlePlus.jpg" },
       new ImageSlider { Source = "~/_Slider/Images/facebook.jpg" }
    });
}
```

and here is my partial view:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <img src="@item.Source" />
    }
</div>
```

Now the problem is that when I create image tag as above, I do not see any image while I can see in my page source that these elements have beeen created. But if I create these tags in HTML, all images are visible. Example:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true">
    <img src="~/_Slider/Images/google.jpg" />
    <img src="~/_Slider/Images/googleplus.jpg" />
    <img src="~/_Slider/Images/facebook.jpg" />
</div>
```

I know I am missing very small thing here but I couldn't figure out what. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: When you see the items created, do they have the correct source i.e. exactly the same as when you create them in html directly?

Comment: try src= "@Url.Content(item.Source)"

Comment: @AsheraH, Yes. Infact I copied above static html code from the page source

Comment: @mww, it worked this way. But can you explain what is the basic difference using `<img src="@item.Source" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@Url.Content` like this, change your View.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content(item.Source)" />

    }
```